# Are ForeignKey and InverseProperty attributes always applied on the many side in EF6.x

Tags: entity-framework-6, foreign-key-relationship

I am using Entity Framework 6.0 code-first approach in my project.

I have two entities - ***entity1*** and ***entity2*** that have a one-to-many relationship, so that one instance of *entity1* can have one or more instances of entity2 and one instance of *entity2* has only a single instance of *entity1*.

**Question**: For above scenario, will ForeignKey attribute always be mentioned in the definition of *entity2* class, or it could also be specified in *entity1* class definition? Similarly, is there a hard and fast rule for InverseProperty attribute that it must always be specified for *entity2*?

**UPDATE 1**

It seems that ForeignKey must always be mentioned in the entity that is on the many side of a relationship i.e. dependent entity, while InverseProperty must always be specified in the entity on the one side of a relationship i.e. principal entity. But, I am not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [ForeignKeyAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The annotation may be placed on the foreign key property and specify the associated navigation property name, or placed on a navigation property and specify the associated foreign key name.

For a one-to-many relationship, only the entity on the "many" side has a foreign key to begin with, so it could only be used on that side.

### [InversePropertyAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.inversepropertyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Specifies the inverse of a navigation property that represents the other end of the same relationship.

A relationship has two ends, and the attribute can be placed on either end.

- For a one-to-many relationship, here's an example of it placed on the "one" end:

  ```cs
  public class Post 
  { 
      public Person CreatedBy { get; set; } 
      public Person UpdatedBy { get; set; }
  }

  public class Person 
  { 
      public int Id { get; set; } 
      public string Name { get; set; } 

      [InverseProperty("CreatedBy")] 
      public List<Post> PostsWritten { get; set; } 

      [InverseProperty("UpdatedBy")] 
      public List<Post> PostsUpdated { get; set; }
  }
  ```

  *https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#Relationships*
- Here's an example on the "many" side:

  ```cs
  [Table("Department", Schema = "dbo")]  
  public class DepartmentMaster  
  {  
      public ICollection<Employee> PrimaryEmployees { get; set; }  
      public ICollection<Employee> SecondaryEmployees { get; set; }  
  }  

  [Table("Employee", Schema = "dbo")]  
  public class Employee  
  {  
      [InverseProperty("PrimaryEmployees")]  
      public DepartmentMaster PrimaryDepartment { get; set; }  

      [InverseProperty("SecondaryEmployees")]  
      public DepartmentMaster SecondaryDepartment { get; set; }  
  }
  ```

  *http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/entity-framework-code-first-data-annotations/*

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Could you  how the foreing key would get named when inverse property is used on the many side? I am assuming the primary keys are DepartmentId for DepartmentMaster table and EmployeeId for Employee table.

Comment: I think EF code-first will add these foreign keys into the Employee table for the example on 'many' side: PrimaryEmployees_EmployeeId and SecondaryEmployees_EmployeeId

Comment: @Sunil: The PrimaryDepartment-PrimaryEmployees relationship will have a foreign key in the `dbo.Employee` table (probably with the names you mentioned). If you included it explicitly, it would be in the `Employee` entity, and you could name it almost anything. I don't think the naming convention is affected by where you place the `[InverseProperty]` attribute.